# "displayOptions" attribute of action bar prior to Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I want to remove the title from the action bar and to add a logo to it.Theme Holo contains an attribute for action bar "android:displayOptions" that permits doing that.Is anything alike in API versions lower than 11? I found a  [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603779/how-to-remove-text-and-logo-or-add-overflow-on-android-actionbar-using-appcompat) suggesting to remove the namespace from that attribute, but it doesn't work (and I also don't quite get that trick). Any viable suggestion? My current code looks like this:

```
<style name="Theme.Alexandru" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Alexandru</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_alexandru</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
</style>
```

Comment: displayOptions in style is not working for me on Toolbar set as Support ActionBar with AppCompat 23.1, I have to call related methods… how did you make it work for you?

Comment: @LouisCAD the displayOptions is an atribute for the action bar; it will be passed as value into the ActionBar object belonging to your activity when the layout will be inflated by the Android framework. But the toolbar is more flexible than the action bar. One way to remove the title is to override the setTitle() method of your activity and always make the title null. And you can add your own TextView or ImageView inside the toolbar layout to display a title or logo.